# Sum of A Finite Series $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac1{6^n}$

Tags: summation, geometric-progressions

I am trying to solve the sum of this finite series:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{6^n}.$$
I am having problems where to start, as it is completely different to the other ones I have done.

Here is the Wolframalpha link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F6^n%2C+i%3D0+to+n

The $\dfrac{1}{6^n}$ just stubs me.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would writing it as $(1/6)^n$ unstub you?

Comment: Its that all the series I have done it has been i and not n.

Comment: @DavidMitra how is it a series if its to the power of n. Its not incrementing?

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  As written, it's $(n+1)\cdot(1/6)^n$ (you're summing $n+1$ terms, all of which are $(1/6)^n$). But it may be a typo, and $(1/6)^i$ was meant.

Comment: @DavidMitra nope its 1/6^n

Comment: @DavidMitra nope its 1/6^n

Comment: @user2079139 Ok, so it is $\;\frac1{6^n}\;$, but are you sure the running index is $\;i\;$ **and not** $\;n\;$ , say from zero to $\;m\;$ or something like that? Because if it is as you say then the sum is trivial.

Comment: @user2079139 $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left (\frac{1}{6}\right )^n=(n+1)\left (\frac{1}{6}\right )^n$$ Are you sure it is $n$ instead of $i$? It could be a typo...

Comment: Yes it is n not i @Timbuc

Comment: Yes it is n and not i. It is how it is in the link @Avz

Comment: @user2079139 Then the comment by AvZ above answers your question...and the sum indeed is trivial.

Comment: @user2079139 Then why are you stuck? It's just adding $\left (\frac{1}{6}\right )^n$ over and over $n+1$ times.

Comment: Ok can anyone explain why? Thanks I just cant see how it comes about @AvZ

Comment: @user2079139 I posted an answer. Check it out.

Comment: Jesus Christ where I am...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\left (\frac{1}{6}\right )^n=k$ for simplicity's sake ($k$ is a constant). It is possible in this case because there is no variable term in the summation. We can do this only when the terms are constant throughout the summation.
Then the sum transforms into
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}k=(n+1)k$$
This is because $i$ starts from $0$ to $n$, and there are $(n+1)$ integers in between. $k$ just gets added $n+1$ times. 
Now, we just substitute the value of $k$ and get the answer as $$(n+1)\left (\frac{1}{6}\right )^n$$